# Ошибка добавления пользовательской библиотеки

Tags: java, library, barcode

Добавлены две пользовательские библиотеки zxing и zbar для чтения и генерации штрих-кодов, через File>New> Jar.файл, добавил их, после в Project Structure тоже добавил их и выбрал implementation во всех уже открытых вопросах используется compile, но в Android studio этого уже нет вместо нее implements и api как их правильно добавить?

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
check.dependsOn 'assembleDebugAndroidTest'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
flavorDimensions "minSdkVersion"

defaultConfig {

    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
}

configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
}

dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
// Firebase Authentication
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
   core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
implementation project(':zbar')
implementation project(':zxing_core')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
  }

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: Судя по .apk это Android приложение или нет? Чем собираешь проект? Как подключал библиотеки в коде? Выложи текст.

Comment: про апргрейдил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Лучше добавлять пользовательские библиотеки с помощью Maven Repository, так Gradle сам все выкачивает куда надо.
В dependencies приложения надо добавить строку `compile group: 'путь', name: 'имя', version: 'версия'`, например `compile group: 'com.yanzhenjie.zbar', name: 'zbar', version: '1.0.0'`
 для  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yanzhenjie.zbar/zbar/1.0.0